# Make ScrollViewer up/down arrow disappear when there is nothing left to scroll

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone, scrollviewer

I've templated a "minimal" `ScrollViewer` with everything but the arrows removed:

[image: Templated ScrollViewer]

I'm looking for a way to hide the arrow for any given direction, when it's not possible to scroll further (so for example the "up" and "left" arrows should be hidden on load).

I thought I'd subclass `ScrollViewer` or `ScrollBar`, but both of those classes are (unlike in WPF) sealed.  So how would it be possible to add this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a `Behavior<ScrollBar>` with a dependency property for the scroll amount.  I applied the behavior to the ScrollBars inside the ScrollViewer control template, and bound the `HorizontalOffset` / `VerticalOffset` properties to the behavior's DPs.  Then, I added some visual states to the ScrollBar's control template.  The behavior is then responsible for updating the visual state when the scroll offset changes.

This is the behavior (actually need 2 extra dependency properties to complete the calculation: size of the viewport, and extent of the scroll bar):

```
public enum ScrollBarDirection { Vertical, Horizontal } ;

public class HideScrollButtonsBehavior : Behavior<ScrollBar>
{
    public ScrollBarDirection Direction { get; set; }

    public double VerticalScrollAmount
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(VerticalScrollAmountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VerticalScrollAmountProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalScrollAmountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("VerticalScrollAmount", typeof(double), typeof(HideScrollButtonsBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(ScrollChanged));

    public double ScrollExtent
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ScrollExtentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScrollExtentProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollExtentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ScrollExtent", typeof(double), typeof(HideScrollButtonsBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public double ViewportExtent
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ViewportExtentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewportExtentProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewportExtentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ViewportExtent", typeof(double), typeof(HideScrollButtonsBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static void ScrollChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.NewValue as double? == null)
            return;

        var owner = (HideScrollButtonsBehavior)sender;
        ScrollBar scrollBar = owner.AssociatedObject;
        double scrollPosition = (double)args.NewValue;

        if (scrollPosition <= 0)
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(scrollBar, owner.Direction + "DownOnly", true);
        else if (scrollPosition >= owner.ScrollExtent - owner.ViewportExtent)
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(scrollBar, owner.Direction + "UpOnly", true);
        else
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(scrollBar, owner.Direction + "Both", true);
    }
}
```

These are applied to the `ScrollBar` instances inside the `ScrollViewer` control template like this (DPs set using a `RelativeSource` binding):

```
<ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" 
            IsTabStop="False"
            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
            Minimum="0" 
            Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behavior:HideScrollButtonsBehavior 
            VerticalScrollAmount="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer},Path=VerticalOffset}" 
            ScrollExtent="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer},Path=ExtentHeight}"
            ViewportExtent="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer},Path=ViewportHeight}"
            Direction="Vertical"
            />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ScrollBar>
```

And finally, the visual states in the `ScrollBar` control template just show/hide the increase/decrease buttons as needed:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="VerticalScrollButtonVisibilityStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="VerticalDownOnly">
        <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.1">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalSmallDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                To="0" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalSmallIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="VerticalUpOnly">
        <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.1">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalSmallDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalSmallIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                To="0" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="VerticalBoth">
        <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.1">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalSmallDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalSmallIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```